# Describe the region $F (|z|≤ 1 )$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find a Linear Fractional Transformation $F$, such that:

1) $F(1) = 0, F(i) = 1, F(−1) = \infty$

2) Describe the region $F(|z| \leq 1)$.

I was able to solve first part and this is what I got;
\begin{align}
      \ F(z) &= \frac{\ (z-1)}{(z+1)} \cdot \frac{\ (i+1)}{(i-1)}
 \end{align}

I fail to understand the second part ?

Is this correct? \begin{align}\ |z| \leq 1  =  x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\end{align}

Comment: 2) is asking for the image of the closed unit disk by $F$.

Comment: yes, like for example is the transformation circle or something else?

Comment: Yes, I think the question also asks which circle is it - if it's a circle.

Comment: I don't know if it's a circle transformation, by 'description' in the question it means what sort of transformation is it which I can't figure out. If you think its a circle transformation, can you explain how you figured it out?

Comment: Well, then you "can't figure out the second part" rather than "fail to understand the second part". At least that would have been a more appropriate wording. Anyway. IIRC, LFTs keep circles, so the unit circle is mapped to the real axis. Substituting in $0$ gives us $F(0) = - \frac{i+1}{i-1}= i$, so the inside of the circle is mapped to the upper half-plane. Thus the answer is the upper half-plane. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

LFTs keep (circle|line)s, so the unit circle is mapped to the real axis. They also keep borders, so the inside of the circle is mapped to either the lower or the upper half-plane. To tell these cases apart, it is enough to substitute in $0$. That gives us $F(0) = - \frac{i+1}{i-1}= i$, so the inside of the circle is mapped to the upper half-plane. Thus the answer is the upper half-plane.